# How to distinguish different shape on the iphone

Tags: iphone, shapes

I want to write a program, it can distinguish different shape automatically. For example, I use my finger draw a square on the screen of iphone, and after my finger leaves the screen, the program could tell me the shape of the graph is "square", but not "diamond" or "circle" and so on.
Now I only hope the program could distinguish some basic graphics, just like "rectangle" "square" "circle" "ellipse" "triangle" and "diamond". I don't quite understand the algorithm,if there are some cases as reference, that's the best thing!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of doing this; but what you're basically doing is handwriting-recognition. This normally uses neural-networks; that's where I would begin.

A fair number of links to resources can be found here:
[Where to start Handwritten Recognition using Neural Network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968501/where-to-start-handwritten-recognition-using-neural-network)

Comment: I just want the program could recognise the shape of the graph, but not using Neural Network. Thank you all the same.