# Google Goggles - An Android Application

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Google goggles is the latest android application designed to search stuffs on the internet by PHOTO.
Now one can upload photo to application and then it will find related profiles and other links on the internet.
I want to know that which mechanism they are using behind that ?

Firstly, I think about color intensity but it might not work..then I think about shape distribution to x axis and y axis with color intensity but i think its not correct.

Now can anyone tell me that which technology they are using in back end ?

Answer (score 2):

> Now can anyone tell me that which technology they are using in back
>   end ?

There are some possibilities. They maybe use neural network like rofls says but I think they are using [Data Mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining) with [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) I think the method is more effective for searching and clustering with very big data. Here a very good explanation of [data mining using genetic algorithm](http://www.uic.edu/classes/idsc/ids572cna/GADataMining_CNA.pdf) and another paper about it [Incremental Clustering in Data Mining](http://www.ijcte.org/papers/161-G262.pdf)

Comment: Than x a lot for your answer..really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are using the [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). Most likely something like [Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), where there is essentially "black box" that predicts the correct thing. See this: [Where to start Handwritten Recognition using Neural Network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968501/where-to-start-handwritten-recognition-using-neural-network), for an example. They train there neural networks on huge servers though, which is why they can deal with complicated images, etc... unlike our computers would be able to.

Comment: Than x a lot for your answer..really appreciated.